# Chaos/Fixed points. I was reading a book by Strogatz and I encountered this.

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, chaos-theory

[image]

Now, I always thought a fixed point implied $f(x)=x$, so somebody tell me, what is he talking about here?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps, you're thinking of the definition of fixed point that arises in discrete dynamics - i.e. the study of the iteration of a function $f$.  The example you're posting here is an example involving a differential equation, which is a different thing.

Comment: Hello.

On the course we did, our professor really didn't go into any detail concerning continuous time, so I don't understand how the concept of a fixed point changes in these conditions.

Comment: I see, I'll expand this to an answer and explain that a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much! I look forward to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you're thinking of the definition of fixed point that arises in discrete dynamics - i.e. the study of the iteration of a function $f$.  For example, if $f(x)=x^2$, then zero is a fixed point, since $f(0)=0$.  The "orbit" of $x=1/2$ tends towards the fixed point.

Now, you're studying a differential equation $x' = x^2-1$.  A solution is a *function* $x(t)$ with the property that $x'(t) = x(t)^2 - 1$.  It's easy to show that one solution is $x(t)=-1$.  This is *fixed* in the sense that it doesn't change.  Most other solutions are given by

$$x(t) = \frac{1-ce^{2t}}{1+ce^{2t}}$$

and many of these functions tend toward $-1$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Alright, I see it now! A point is "fixed" in the sense it doesn't change, therefore $x'(t)$ must be 0, as it is velocity. 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it just a general rule in continuous time that if you approach a fixed point from "above", it's an attractor?

Comment: Fixed point means fixed, period.  The fixed point may be attractive (or called stable, in this context) or repulsive (unstable).